# Spring MVC view doesn't receive model attributes

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm interested in learning Spring MVC and I have a very simple Spring MVC application with a simple login form.  The login form sends a POST request to a controller, the controller currently is just a passthrough that just gets the post parameters and sets a few attributes in the Model and passes to another view, this second view displays these attributes.  The view that gets presented after the controller doesn't have the model parameters available, I'm not sure why.

The LoginController has the correct values for the parameters password and username.

Thank you,

Below are the relevant snippets:

View resolver in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypackage" />
```

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue and it wasn't Spring MVC related.

At the top of my errorpage.jsp I put

```
<%@ taglib prefix="core" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

but then I used the commmands

```
<c:out value="${username}"/>
```

I modified my taglib include to be

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

and that fixed it...Not sure why Netbeans 7.2 didn't at least give me a warning...